# Why am I getting errors on incorrect lines in Eclipse? What can I do about it?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

My script <strike>works</strike> seemed to be working perfectly well, but Eclipse 3.7.2 was telling me I had multiple errors on a random set of empty lines:

[image: Screenshot of Eclipse's spurious error markers]

When I deleted the lines, all the errors bunched up into one lump, like this:

[image: All the errors bunched into one line]

Here's the list it was giving me:

[image]

---

### EDIT

It turns out I did have an error in my code - I was using `=` to check for equality in an if statement. When I corrected this, ALL of the errors disappeared.

Why did that mistake cause the effects above?

Comment: Did you try put an empty statement ";" at the start of your js file?

Comment: @Furqan is that a suggestion to help fix, or a question? I didn't do that, no.

Comment: @Furqan thanks, didn't do anything though :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be eclipse getting out of sync.  I would do a clean and/or a refresh.  In Eclipse sometimes things get cached.  Sometimes I have to restart eclipse with the -clean option and everything clears up.

Since the script is working, that is what I'd try first.

Again, I know there are settings in eclipse that you can change for errors, but I don't believe any settings changes will show or hide errors on blank lines.  At least that I'm aware of.

I assume that while you were working on the script there was originally no errors, but at some point during that process or when you completed it and saved it, then the errors showed up, correct?  Did you try a full reboot?

It looks like eclipse is caching an old version of the file.  To find out and stop guessing, use Firefox with firebug.

Steps:

1. Go to the net tab and ensure the script is loaded,
2. then look at the code in the script tab (be sure to select yours) to ensure it's what you are seeing in eclipse.  If the loaded code is identical to your code, then you still have the problem and go to 3. otherwise, you know the issue is it's not loading the script properly.
3. Show us the script code.
4. Look in the console, if there is a javascript error in the script, it will show up there.

I've had this throw me more than once, thinking a script was loaded when it was an older version of it and didn't load the newest.  I've also had eclipse cache older versions of server side code and not refresh changes.

Here are some screenshots of firebug tabs during debugging:

[Firebug Net tab loaded scripts example](http://i45.tinypic.com/344fn9x.jpg)

[Firebug Console tab with simple error example](http://i48.tinypic.com/14d10r8.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just tried both of these things, but neither helped :-(

Comment: Did you use firebug to find the issue?

Comment: No, I copied my js into another file and deleted each function in turn until I found the one that was causing the problems. I then deleted parts of this from the inside out until the errors disappeared. It was then clear which line was causing the problem, and I spotted my mistake.

Comment: How would you have used firebug to do this? If you explain why and how to do that in an answer, it might be the most appropriate one for this question.

Comment: Look at the steps under #4. It catches js errors in the console or you can use console log.

Comment: Interesting. The problems you describe with caching sound like something that could be avoided if settings on one's dev machine were chosen appropriately. That seems like a good topic for another question.



As I'm making an Android app which depends on java libs, I can't use your your Firebug protocol. It might be useful for others in this situation though, so it seems like the best answer to the question. I get console logs of js errors anyway in Eclipse, so that solves my problem.

Comment: Firebug would have nailed it in 2 seconds.  How long did your way take?

Comment: Well I have to load my app into the emulator and use the functionality in the script I was writing, so it takes about 30s?

No caching problems with the app btw, which I guess is a boon :-)

Comment: When I get some time I'll add pics.  Firebug has saved me hours of debugging, so I made a donation to the project.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, it is the validation that was causing you the errors. If you go to Project->Properties->Javascript

Apart from the ECMAScript Compliance checking it will also warn you for other things.You can see an option called Errors/Warnings under sub menu Validation which has some default settings. To see them check Enable project specific settings and toggle Potential programming problems.